# Signal handler of old window getting replaced by new windows signal handler GTK+

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk2

My GUI application has 2 windows.
The Main window destroy signal is set to quit the application using `gtk_main_quit`.

The other window destroy signal is set just to destroy that particular window using method `gtk_widget_destroy`.

From Main window we launch the other window. After launching the other window when we click on close `button(X)` then the other window successfully destroys but the main window keeps on running, so far all good.

Now when we click on Main windows close `button(X)` it did not exits the whole application rather it just destroys the main window and the process keeps on running.

If I don't launch the other window from main window then everything works fine and application exits successfully.

Here is a sample code which reproduces the issue:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class OtherWindow {
    private:
        int number;

        GtkWidget* window;

        GtkWidget* button;

    public:
        OtherWindow(int num);

        static void read_number(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data);

};

OtherWindow::OtherWindow(int num)
{
    number = num;
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Read Number");

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), button);

    // signal handler
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_widget_destroy), NULL);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(OtherWindow::read_number), this);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();

}

void OtherWindow::read_number(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    OtherWindow* other_win = static_cast<OtherWindow*>(data);
    cout << other_win->number << endl;
}

class MainWindow {

    private:
        GtkWidget* window;

        GtkWidget* button;

    public:
        MainWindow();

        static void open_other_window(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data);
};


MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Open Another Window");

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), button);

    // signal handler
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(MainWindow::open_other_window), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();    
}

void MainWindow::open_other_window(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    OtherWindow other(10);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc,&argv);

    MainWindow win;

}
```

One more doubt is that when I tried removing `gtk_main` loop from the `OtherWindow` constructor then application exits successfully but if I remove `gtk_main` loop from `OtherWindow` constructor and then click on the button present on the Other window to access the member variable using pointer reference my application then gets segmentation fault.

Also I am not using `gtkmm` because I have few limitations as I have to run application on old Solaris servers which don't have compiler to support the same.

It would be a very common thing to launch other windows from main window, I think I am missing something basic. Anything which can help here.

Comment: Why do you run multiple mainloops?

Comment: Don't we have to run main loop for each toplevel window.
Anyway if you don't run the OtherWindow main loop it will dump core (Segmentation fault) as I have mentioned in the post.
The reason why it dumps core because once the OtherWindow is instantiated it immediately gets deleted as there is no blocking function in between and when then later in its signal handler we try to use the object reference it will dump core as the object is already freed.

Comment: Earlier I was indeed using only one main loop but it dumped as I am writing this comment I am pretty much sure I found the solution. For some problems when I ask a question then only my mind works and see now I found what went wrong. Let me try and confirm back.
Thanks for making my brain think hard enough.!!

Comment: Oh yes I found it

Comment: Thanks @jku actually while adding second main loop I was getting a feeling that it is not right way to do but then I found one example on internet making use of two main loops so I just happened to use it as at that time I had no idea what dumped core. Anyway you made me think again and it helped feeling so light now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more question answering myself.
First thing to note here is why I am using two main loops as noted by @jku.
I was using two main loops because earlier with only one loop my process was dumping core and I didn't concentrated on checking what went wrong rather I started thinking in other way and inserted one more main loop which was not required.

Now why it was dumping core just struck my mind as I was writing comments on my post. It was object which was getting freed whose reference I was still using in the OtherWindow's Button's signal handler.
As I created object on the stack and as soon as the function ended the object got deleted but later in signal handler when I tried using it, it will definitely dump core which I just got to know.

Hence, the way I handled seg fault by introducing one more main loop was a very bad idea as we should be using only one main loop, as introducing more main loops caused further other issues as stated in the post.

So, only few changes in above code makes everything right:

First remove the gtk main loop from OtherWindow Constructor.

Second create the OtherWindow object dynamically as below:

```
void MainWindow::open_other_window(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    OtherWindow* other = new OtherWindow(10);
}
```